# Table is not visible for EntityManaged in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have created a table in mysqladmin console, fill it with some date and now I would like connect to this DB with JPA (Hibernate) and query it. So I created entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service")
public class Service implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    //blablba
}
```

I am able to inject EntityManager to the CDI bean but the query fails on `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SERVICE" not found; SQL statement`

```
@Model
public class ServicesBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager manager;

    public List getAllServices() {
        return (List<Service>) manager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Service s").getResultList();
    }
}
```

I am using MariaDB 5.5.34, I tried both MySQL and MariaDB driver (still getting same exception) and here is my `persistence.xml`.

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I also tried to connect with [DBInspect](http://www.dbinspect.com/) tool and table is correctly displayed there and I can query it. Also note I have set `javax.persistence.jdbc.user` to a nonexisting user and still getting the same result so problem probably lies in the connection - but in that case I don't get the exception about table not found.

Comment: are you sure that the user "user" have the needed privileges on table service ?

Comment: Yes, I granted them. I tried to log as this user both from the console and DBInspect?

Comment: check if service table is in user schema, if not you may either check privileges or set default schema in config files

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to access DB with the root account and I had the same result.

Comment: I realized that the problem is the connection, not the user - I tried it with nonexisting user account which I put into `persistence.xml` and I am having the same result.

Comment: You may need to check the case sensitivity of table name.

Comment: I did it, that's why I am explicitly setting table name in `@Table(name = "Service")`

Comment: Your propery `"hbm2ddl.auto"` is wrong. It should be `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was actually caused by Wildfly - the deployed project was using ExampleDS datasource and it was completely ignoring my `pesistence.xml`. So I created new datasource with correct values, added a reference to it in `persistence.xml` and now it works. But I am still wondering how to connect to DB without configuring proprietary datasource.

Answer (score 0):

With WildFly 8.1.0.

I get a strange "table not found" if I use the code below

```
@Stateless
public class ClientiPersoaneFiziceFacade extends AbstractFacade<ClientiPersoaneFizice> 
{
   private EntityManager em;

   @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ManufacturerMaintainanceWPU")
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

}
```

My solution is to use this code:

```
@Stateless
public class ClientiPersoaneFiziceFacade extends AbstractFacade<ClientiPersoaneFizice> 
{
    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
       if (emf == null)
       {
          emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ManufacturerMaintainanceWPU");
       }

       if (em == null)
       {
              em = emf.createEntityManager();
       }

       return em;
     }
}
```

My persistence.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="ManufacturerMaintainanceWPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>entities.ClientiPersoaneFizice</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

Comment: Please, also add comment to provide some details for your fix.

Comment: In my case Wildfly raises
a "Table not found" if I use this
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ManufacturerMaintainanceWPU") 
The solution is shown in my post.